# CSS Truncate inline text only if needed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a reusable component such that it will stay inline but truncate its contents whenever it overflows. What makes it trickier is that I need to have an icon on the right.

The main issue is that I need the icon to stay on the same line, so I compensate for it in the width of the truncated text (`width: calc(100% - 40px)`), which makes any non-truncating example be that much shorter than it's normal width.

See the snippet below and how the short example is barely visible.

```css
body, .container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.quantity-value {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.value-and-icon-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.truncated-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Example 1: short -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="quantity-value">
    <div class="value-and-icon-wrapper">
      <span class="truncated-text">67</span>
      <span class="icon">ℹ️</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  other content
</div>

<!-- Example 2: long -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="quantity-value">
    <div class="value-and-icon-wrapper">
      <span class="truncated-text">68 long text starting now lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <span class="icon">ℹ️</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  other content
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by truncate?

Comment: I mean cut the text short and add ellipsis.

Comment: there’s an overflow property for that, did you google this?

Comment: Please check the snippet above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using a lot of `inline-block` and the width of `inline-block` is defined by its content so if you set `100% - 40px` for a child item, it means its width minus `40px`

Try to do it differently like below using flexbox:

```css
body, .container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.quantity-value {
  display: inline-flex;
  max-width: calc(100% - 16px); /* don't forget to account for margin here */
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.icon {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.truncated-text {
  flex:1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- Example 1: short -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="quantity-value">
      <span class="truncated-text">67</span>
      <span class="icon">ℹ️</span>
  </div>
  other content
</div>

<!-- Example 2: long -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="quantity-value">
      <span class="truncated-text">68 long text starting now lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <span class="icon">ℹ️</span>
  </div>
  other content
</div>
```

Without flexbox you can do it like below:

```css
body, .container {
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.quantity-value {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 16px); /* don't forget to account for margin/padding here */
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding-right:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}

.icon {
  padding-left: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  
}
.truncated-text {
  display:block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- Example 1: short -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="quantity-value">
      <span class="truncated-text">67</span>
      <span class="icon">ℹ️</span>
  </div>
  other content
</div>

<!-- Example 2: long -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="quantity-value">
      <span class="truncated-text">68 long text starting now lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <span class="icon">ℹ️</span>
  </div>
  other content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the style `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the div that contains the text to be truncated.

[MDN Documentation for text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)